# Can Html5's FileReader read Images as base64

Tags: javascript, html, image

I'm using a FileReader to display images choosed by the user with a FileUploader into an img

```
    $('#FileUploader').onchange(function(){
    var oFile = $('#attached-file')[0].files[0];
    oReader.readAsDataURL(oFile);
            oReader.onload = function (e) {...//partfn..}
}
```

Anyway the img has initially takes the user's profile image which is loaded from the database as a base64 image.In that {partfn} there are some things that i want to apply even for the initial image so i thought about doing this:

```
if (!oFile)
 oFile= //receive the image from database so the FileReader read it.
```

but i failed using readAsDataURL and ReadAsBinary .
Thank you

Comment: is there even a file in your file?

Comment: yes the first code is trigered when when there is file in the FileUploader
the second code is when there is no file (that's why i'm using ajax to get a file from database)